Put function parameters as normally idented block with clang-format
I have C++ code, and I want format it by Goole style with two differences:

Code ident: 4 spaces
Column limit: 80
Function parameters: normally idented block
Function arguments: normally idented block

The form I want to get as follow:
SomeClass::SomeClass(
    OraQuery *p_query,
    ListView *p_list_view,
    bool p_fetch_all
) :
    m_query(p_query),
    m_list_view(p_list_view),
    m_fetch_all(p_fetch_all
) {
    if (!m_fetch_all) {
        // ...
        someFunction(
            a1,
            a2,
            a3);
    }
    // ...
}

I found suggestion, to set AlignAfterOpenBracket to BlockIndent, but it didn't help.
The configuration I have now:
{
    BasedOnStyle: Google,
    IndentWidth: 4,
    TabWidth: 4,
    AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent,
    ColumnLimit: 80
}


Honestly, I absolutely wouldn't recommend such a style: Member initialisations distinguish hardly from the parameters and first code line hardly from the initialisations. At very least place the colon on next line instead of appending it and use Allman style for braces. Anyone having to read your code will be grateful.

IMO this looks extremely ugly and hard to tell where the function starts. And it just so happened that the previous question I looked at asked why use multiple lines when you can do everything in a single line? :-) Different taste, obviously.

Are there two or four differences?

Which version of clang-format?  The version I have is 18.1.4.  It makes a different only in that settings have changed, defaults have changed, and clang-format capabilities have evolved.

Here's a clang-format configurator tool to help figure out your preferred configuration settings.

OK, I splitted the initizlization. Version is 17.0.6, and thanx for the tool, I will play with.

Personally I prefer to use BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma to nicely distinguish initializer list from from constructor arguments and constructor code. It also reduces number of merge conflicts when someone adds new field.

OK, it seems that these three options almost makes the magic:
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false

It was enough for me.
